# Use python to parse only cells formatted as input from Excel file

Tags: python, excel, parsing

I have got a spreadsheet, in which some cells are marked as `Input` cells. I would like to extract only those cells into a Python variable using, for example, the `excel_read()` function from `pandas`.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you know beforehand where they are you can specify which columns to use by invoking the `parse_cols` parameter. But it doesn't look like by reading through the [`pandas.read_excel` function docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) that you can programmatically select certain cells within the function call.

However, you could always read in everything and then discard what you don't need based on how `Input` cells are represented in the DataFrame. Without an example it would hard to guess how to do this currently, but pandas is good for this type of data cleaning.